# Editing the theme inside `gnome-shell-theme.gresource` has prevented Ubuntu from booting?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, themes

**If you run Ubuntu**, and you have a moment would you mind please checking the contents of two files for me, it could be really useful. See the "IF YOU ARE RUNNING UBUNTU:" paragraph.

I was naively editing `gnome-shell-theme.gresource` while trying to edit the login/lock-screen background. The full path is given below:

```
/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource
```

Specifically, I changed what was under the `#lockDialogGroup` section. This has since prevented my laptop from booting.

**IF YOU ARE RUNNING UBUNTU:**
Could you please let me know what is under your`#lockDialogGroup` in both:
`/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource` and
`/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell-classic.css` (I made a change here too at one point but thought I successfully edited it back after it had no effect). This might save my bacon.

When trying to boot the following appears (basic terminal-like white text against black background):

```
/dev/sda2: clean 12345678/12345678 files 12345678/12345678 blocks
```

Then, a [graphically superior message comes up](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7460774/65824196-14f6e100-e222-11e9-8537-93c27d695adb.jpg) (grey text against a white background):

> **:( Oh no! Something has gone wrong!** A problem has occurred and the
> system can’t recover. Please contact a system administrator

Using ctrl + alt + F3 I was able to login without a GUI, and undo the changes based on the contents of the same file. This was possible as I could boot another laptop from USB and select "Try Ubuntu", then just `sudo nano gnome-shell-theme.gresource`.

This did not get me past the error...

---

**Some basic troubleshooting:**

I ran a bad blocks test to be safe, but it found no HDD failures.

I booted in recovery mode and selected fsck but this occurs:

```
/lib/recovery-mode/recover-menu: line 80: /etc/default/rcS: No such file or directory
fsck from util-linux 2.34
/dev/sda2 is mounted
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

I also reinstalled GRUB from the Ubuntu on my USB just in case. This didn't seem to do anything.

When I accidentally held F4 on boot and in addition to the the /dev/sda2 message I am given two messages saying there is a `problem loading x.509 certificates -65`.

---

Any ideas and indeed criticisms welcome. I would be particularly keen to know if I can reinstall EVERYTHING inside my `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme` file. Can one reinstall the default OS theme from terminal? Thank you for reading the above, I did try to balance detail with brevity.

Comment: The trying Ubuntu from USB actually gave me slightly different files than my machine's Ubuntu. The contents of `themes` was a lot more sparse for instance. A total reinstall and some other bits solved it. It's 3am here, so I will post the answer tomorrow in case any muppet decides to do what I did.

Comment: @SolebaySharp can you logon via tty?

Comment: I found a solution, but I appreciate your enquiries. It's reassuring when you feel you have more minds than just your own set on the task at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found a way to undo this mess.

Use **ctrl** + **alt** + **F3** to access tty, basically interface with the computer without any GUI.

Purge the mutilated version of gdm3 that is punishing its creator who made edits without a backup.

```
Sudo apt purge gdm3
```

Go and delete your Yaru folder manually if it still exists. I got a message saying mine did.

```
cd /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/

ls
```

Yup, damn thing was still there, clinging on for dear life.

```
sudo rm -r Yaru
```

Install fresh gdm3

```
sudo apt install gdm3

sudo apt install-desktop-theme-minimal
```

Start user interface by running...

```
startx
```

Reconfigure gdm3

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

The above only seemed to get me from a boot-loop to a login-loop so I also had to change some permissions...

```
sudo chmod a+wt /tmp
```

Hopefully, you can now successfully login. And if you want to edit your login screen you can use [this script from thiggy01](https://github.com/thiggy01/ubuntu-20.04-change-gdm-background) instead of bricking your OS.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download a new iso.
2. Make a bootable pendrive.
3. Boot from the pendrive on the machine.
4. Navigate to `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/`.
5. Copy the Yaru folder from the pendrive to the same path but your physical machine.

Do everything through the Ex terminal:
`sudo cp -R /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru` < path of your physical machine>  Ex: `/media/oli/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/`

This worked for me :)